# Swipeleft to delete not working in expandable height listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, swipe-gesture

The application which i am creating has an expandable list view in which i have added the option of swipe to edit and delete.I have added those option but when i run the application it doesn't shows the swipe option even i have tried with another list view but there it works fine.
 I have used the swipe option inside the base adapter can anyone tell me why the swipe functionality doesn't works in expandable list view.

Expandablelistview:

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_NONE = 0;
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_X = 1;
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_Y = 2;

public static final int DIRECTION_LEFT = 1;
public static final int DIRECTION_RIGHT = -1;
private int mDirection = 1;//swipe from right to left by default

private int MAX_Y = 5;
private int MAX_X = 3;
private float mDownX;
private float mDownY;
private int mTouchState;
private int mTouchPosition;
private DaybookSwipeMenuLayout mTouchView;
private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeListener;

private DaybookSwipeMenuCreator mMenuCreator;
private OnMenuItemClickListener mOnMenuItemClickListener;
private OnMenuStateChangeListener mOnMenuStateChangeListener;
private Interpolator mCloseInterpolator;
private Interpolator mOpenInterpolator;



boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    MAX_X = dp2px(MAX_X);
    MAX_Y = dp2px(MAX_Y);
    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_NONE;
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (isExpanded()) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(new DaybookSwipeMenuAdapter(getContext(), adapter) {
        @Override
        public void createMenu(DaybookSwipeMenu menu) {
            if (mMenuCreator != null) {
                mMenuCreator.create(menu);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DaybookSwipeMenuView view, DaybookSwipeMenu menu,
                                int index) {
            boolean flag = false;
            if (mOnMenuItemClickListener != null) {
                flag = mOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(
                        view.getPosition(), menu, index);
            }
            if (mTouchView != null && !flag) {
                mTouchView.smoothCloseMenu();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setCloseInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
    mCloseInterpolator = interpolator;
}

public void setOpenInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
    mOpenInterpolator = interpolator;
}

public Interpolator getOpenInterpolator() {
    return mOpenInterpolator;
}

public Interpolator getCloseInterpolator() {
    return mCloseInterpolator;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //在拦截处处理，在滑动设置了点击事件的地方也能swip，点击时又不能影响原来的点击事件
    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = ev.getX();
            mDownY = ev.getY();
            boolean handled = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_NONE;
            mTouchPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
            View view = getChildAt(mTouchPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition());

            //只在空的时候赋值 以免每次触摸都赋值，会有多个open状态
            if (view instanceof DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) {
                //如果有打开了 就拦截.
                if (mTouchView != null && mTouchView.isOpen() && !inRangeOfView(mTouchView.getMenuView(), ev)) {
                    return true;
                }
                mTouchView = (DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) view;
                mTouchView.setSwipeDirection(mDirection);
            }
            //如果摸在另外个view
            if (mTouchView != null && mTouchView.isOpen() && view != mTouchView) {
                handled = true;
            }

            if (mTouchView != null) {
                mTouchView.onSwipe(ev);
            }
            return handled;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float dy = Math.abs((ev.getY() - mDownY));
            float dx = Math.abs((ev.getX() - mDownX));
            if (Math.abs(dy) > MAX_Y || Math.abs(dx) > MAX_X) {
                //每次拦截的down都把触摸状态设置成了TOUCH_STATE_NONE 只有返回true才会走onTouchEvent 所以写在这里就够了
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_NONE) {
                    if (Math.abs(dy) > MAX_Y) {
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_Y;
                    } else if (dx > MAX_X) {
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_X;
                        if (mOnSwipeListener != null) {
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeStart(mTouchPosition);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && mTouchView == null)
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            int oldPos = mTouchPosition;
            mDownX = ev.getX();
            mDownY = ev.getY();
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_NONE;

            mTouchPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());

            if (mTouchPosition == oldPos && mTouchView != null
                    && mTouchView.isOpen()) {
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_X;
                mTouchView.onSwipe(ev);
                return true;
            }

            View view = getChildAt(mTouchPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition());

            if (mTouchView != null && mTouchView.isOpen()) {
                mTouchView.smoothCloseMenu();
                mTouchView = null;
                // return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                // try to cancel the touch event
                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                if (mOnMenuStateChangeListener != null) {
                    mOnMenuStateChangeListener.onMenuClose(oldPos);
                }
                return true;
            }
            if (view instanceof DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) {
                mTouchView = (DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) view;
                mTouchView.setSwipeDirection(mDirection);
            }
            if (mTouchView != null) {
                mTouchView.onSwipe(ev);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //有些可能有header,要减去header再判断
            mTouchPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) - getHeaderViewsCount();
            //如果滑动了一下没完全展现，就收回去，这时候mTouchView已经赋值，再滑动另外一个不可以swip的view
            //会导致mTouchView swip 。 所以要用位置判断是否滑动的是一个view
            if (!mTouchView.getSwipEnable() || mTouchPosition != mTouchView.getPosition()) {
                break;
            }
            float dy = Math.abs((ev.getY() - mDownY));
            float dx = Math.abs((ev.getX() - mDownX));
            if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_X) {
                if (mTouchView != null) {
                    mTouchView.onSwipe(ev);
                }
                getSelector().setState(new int[]{0});
                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                return true;
            } else if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_NONE) {
                if (Math.abs(dy) > MAX_Y) {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_Y;
                } else if (dx > MAX_X) {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_X;
                    if (mOnSwipeListener != null) {
                        mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeStart(mTouchPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_X) {
                if (mTouchView != null) {
                    boolean isBeforeOpen = mTouchView.isOpen();
                    mTouchView.onSwipe(ev);
                    boolean isAfterOpen = mTouchView.isOpen();
                    if (isBeforeOpen != isAfterOpen && mOnMenuStateChangeListener != null) {
                        if (isAfterOpen) {
                            mOnMenuStateChangeListener.onMenuOpen(mTouchPosition);
                        } else {
                            mOnMenuStateChangeListener.onMenuClose(mTouchPosition);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isAfterOpen) {
                        mTouchPosition = -1;
                        mTouchView = null;
                    }
                }
                if (mOnSwipeListener != null) {
                    mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeEnd(mTouchPosition);
                }
                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void smoothOpenMenu(int position) {
    if (position >= getFirstVisiblePosition()
            && position <= getLastVisiblePosition()) {
        View view = getChildAt(position - getFirstVisiblePosition());
        if (view instanceof DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) {
            mTouchPosition = position;
            if (mTouchView != null && mTouchView.isOpen()) {
                mTouchView.smoothCloseMenu();
            }
            mTouchView = (DaybookSwipeMenuLayout) view;
            mTouchView.setSwipeDirection(mDirection);
            mTouchView.smoothOpenMenu();
        }
    }
}

public void smoothCloseMenu(){
    if (mTouchView != null && mTouchView.isOpen()) {
        mTouchView.smoothCloseMenu();
    }
}

private int dp2px(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
            getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void setMenuCreator(DaybookSwipeMenuCreator menuCreator) {
    this.mMenuCreator = menuCreator;
}

public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(
        OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnMenuItemClickListener = onMenuItemClickListener;
}

public void setOnSwipeListener(OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener) {
    this.mOnSwipeListener = onSwipeListener;
}

public void setOnMenuStateChangeListener(OnMenuStateChangeListener onMenuStateChangeListener) {
    mOnMenuStateChangeListener = onMenuStateChangeListener;
}

public static interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
    boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, DaybookSwipeMenu menu, int index);
}

public static interface OnSwipeListener {
    void onSwipeStart(int position);

    void onSwipeEnd(int position);
}

public static interface OnMenuStateChangeListener {
    void onMenuOpen(int position);

    void onMenuClose(int position);
}

public void setSwipeDirection(int direction) {
    mDirection = direction;
}

/**
 * 判断点击事件是否在某个view内
 *
 * @param view
 * @param ev
 * @return
 */
public static boolean inRangeOfView(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    if (ev.getRawX() < x || ev.getRawX() > (x + view.getWidth()) || ev.getRawY() < y || ev.getRawY() > (y + view.getHeight())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

BaseAdapter class having the swipe list option:

```
public class Daybook_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Daybook> entriesdaybook;
ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists;
Daybooklist_adapter adapter;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
LinearLayout emptyy;
double totalamountin=0.0;
ExpandableHeightListView daybookdetailviewlist;
public Daybook_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Daybook> list) {

    this.context = context;
    entriesdaybook = list;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {

    return entriesdaybook.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return entriesdaybook.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook, null);

    }


    Daybook m = entriesdaybook.get(position);
    final TextView tv_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_date);
    final TextView tv_cashin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_cashin);
    final TextView tv_cashout = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_cashout);
    final TextView tv_totalamt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.daybook_total_amt);
    //final String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    String s = m.getDate();
    emptyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    daybookdetailviewlist = (ExpandableHeightListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detaillist_daybook);
    String[] spiliter = s.split("-");
    String year = spiliter[0];
    String month = spiliter[1];
    String date = spiliter[2];
    if (month.startsWith("01")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jan" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Feb" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Mar" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Apr" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "May" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jun" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jul" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Aug" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Sep" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Oct" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Nov" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Dec" + year);
    }


   /* if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker")) {
        tv_cashin.setText("\u20B9" + "0");
    } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker")) {
        tv_cashin.setText("\u20B9" + "0");
    }*/

        tv_cashin.setText("\u20B9" + m.getCashin());
        tv_cashout.setText("\u20B9" + m.getCashout());
      double one = Double.parseDouble(m.getCashin());
       double two = Double.parseDouble(m.getCashout());
       double three  = one+two;
       tv_totalamt.setText("\u20B9" +String.valueOf(three) );

    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);


    daybooklists = databaseHandler.getAllDaywisedaybookdetails(s);

    adapter = new Daybooklist_adapter((Activity) context, daybooklists);
    if (adapter != null) {
        if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
            emptyy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            daybookdetailviewlist.setAdapter(adapter);

            DaybookSwipeMenuCreator creator = new DaybookSwipeMenuCreator() {


                @Override
                public void create(DaybookSwipeMenu menu) {
                    // create "open" item
                    DaybookSwipeMenuItem openItem = new DaybookSwipeMenuItem(
                            (Activity) context);
                    // set item background
                    openItem.setBackground(R.color.colorPrimary);
                    // set item width
                    openItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));

                    // set item title
                    openItem.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pencil));
                    openItem.setTitle("Edit");
                    // set item title fontsize
                    openItem.setTitleSize(15);
                    // set item title font color
                    openItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // add to menu
                    menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

                    // create "delete" item
                    DaybookSwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new DaybookSwipeMenuItem(
                            (Activity) context);
                    // set item background
                    deleteItem.setBackground(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                    // set item width

                    deleteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                    // set a icon
                    deleteItem.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete));
                    deleteItem.setTitle("Delete");
                    deleteItem.setTitleSize(15);
                    deleteItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // add to menu
                    menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
                }
            };
            daybookdetailviewlist.setMenuCreator(creator);

            final ArrayList<Daybooklist> finalListet = daybooklists;
            daybookdetailviewlist.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ExpandableHeightListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(final int position, DaybookSwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                    // Coconuttype item = finalListet.get(position);
                //    final String farmername = finalListet.get(position).getFarmername();
                  //  final String farmermobno = finalListet.get(position).getFarmermobno();
                  //  final String farmerlocation = finalListet.get(position).getFarmerlocation();
                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            // open
                            // open(item);
                            //  String farmername = finalListet.get(position).getFarmername();
                            //  String farmermobno = finalListet.get(position).getFarmermobno();
                            //  String farmerlocation =finalListet.get(position).getFarmerlocation();
                            Log.e("Editclicked", "edt");
                         //   Log.e("farmername", farmername);
                         //   Log.e("farmermobno", farmermobno);
                         //   Log.e("farmerlocation", farmerlocation);
                           /* Intent k = new Intent(context, FarmerEdit_Activity.class);
                            k.putExtra("farmername", farmername);
                            k.putExtra("farmermobno", farmermobno);
                            k.putExtra("farmerlocation", farmerlocation);
                            context.startActivity(k);*/

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // delete
                            //delete(item);
                            Log.e("Deleteclicked", "del");
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    context);
                            alert.setTitle("Delete");
                            alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete  ");
                            alert.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //do your work here
                                    finalListet.remove(position);
                                    //databaseHandlerOtherChgs.deleteCoconut(item.getCoconuttype());
                                  //  Log.e("farmername", farmername);
                                 //   Log.e("farmermobno", farmermobno);
                                  //  Log.e("farmerlocation", farmerlocation);
                                   /* databasehandler.deletefarmercontacts(farmername, farmermobno);
                                    databasehandler.deletedaybookdetails(farmername, farmermobno);
                                    databasehandler.deletefarmeradvance(farmername, farmermobno);
                                    databasehandler.deletefarmerbillbookdetails(farmername, farmermobno);
                                    databasehandler.deletefarmertradedetails(farmername, farmermobno);
                                    fadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    Intent k = getIntent();
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(k);*/


                                }
                            });
                            alert.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            alert.show();

                           /* finalListet.remove(position);
                            databaseHandlerOtherChgs.deleteCoconut(item.getCoconuttype());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Intent k = getIntent();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(k);*/
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // set SwipeListener
            daybookdetailviewlist.setOnSwipeListener(new ExpandableHeightListView.OnSwipeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
                    // swipe start
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
                    // swipe end
                }
            });

            // set MenuStateChangeListener
            daybookdetailviewlist.setOnMenuStateChangeListener(new ExpandableHeightListView.OnMenuStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuOpen(int position) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMenuClose(int position) {
                }
            });
        }
    }else {
        daybookdetailviewlist.setEmptyView(emptyy);
    }

    daybookdetailviewlist.setExpanded(true);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //todo disable the comments for farmer individual transaction


        }
    });
    return convertView;

}
private int dp2px(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void setTransactionList(ArrayList<Daybook> newList) {
    entriesdaybook = newList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Please refer this: https://github.com/steelkiwi/ListView-Swipe-to-Delete & https://github.com/steelkiwi/ListView-Swipe-to-Delete/blob/master/demo/src/com/skd/swipetodelete/explist/MainExpListActivity.java It will help you

Answer (score 2):

I m posting code here , i hope it helps u

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Click this:notify data set changed and re-open the opened menu" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn">

        <com.allen.expandablelistview.SwipeMenuExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> mAppList;
    private AppAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeMenuExpandableListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAppList = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(l);
        // 1. Create View
        listView = (SwipeMenuExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stick_mode", false)) {
            // 2. Set where does the menu item stick with
            /**
             * STICK_TO_ITEM_RIGHT_SIDE: Stick with item right side, when swipe,
             * it moves from outside of screen .
             **/
            /**
             * STICK_TO_SCREEN: stick with the screen, it was covered and don't
             * move ,item moves then menu show.
             **/
            listView.setmMenuStickTo(SwipeMenuListView.STICK_TO_SCREEN);
        }
        // 3. Create Adapter and set. It controls data,
        // item view,clickable ,swipable ...
        mAdapter = new AppAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // 4. Set OnItemLongClickListener
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id);
                int childPosition, groupPosition;
                if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                    childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
                    groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);

                    // do your per-item callback here
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "long click on group " + groupPosition + " child " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    return true; // true if we consumed the click, false if not

                } else if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                    groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                    // do your per-group callback here
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "long click on group " + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true; // true if we consumed the click, false if not

                } else {
                    // null item; we don't consume the click
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // 5.Set OnGroupClickListener
        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "group " + groupPosition + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // 6.Set OnChildClickListener
        listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "group " + groupPosition + " child " + childPosition + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // 7. Create and set a SwipeMenuExpandableCreator
        // define the group and child creator function
        SwipeMenuExpandableCreator creator = new SwipeMenuExpandableCreator() {
            @Override
            public void createGroup(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // Create different menus depending on the view type
                switch (menu.getViewType()) {
                    case 0:
                        createMenu1(menu);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        createMenu2(menu);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        createMenu3(menu);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void createChild(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // Create different menus depending on the view type
                switch (menu.getViewType()) {
                    case 0:
                        createMenu1(menu);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        createMenu2(menu);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        createMenu3(menu);
                        break;
                }
            }

            private void createMenu1(SwipeMenu menu) {
                SwipeMenuItem item1 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item1.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xE5, 0x18, 0x5E)));
                item1.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);
                menu.addMenuItem(item1);
                SwipeMenuItem item2 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item2.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9, 0xCE)));
                item2.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_good);
                menu.addMenuItem(item2);
            }

            private void createMenu2(SwipeMenu menu) {
                SwipeMenuItem item1 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item1.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xE5, 0xE0, 0x3F)));
                item1.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
                menu.addMenuItem(item1);
                SwipeMenuItem item2 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item2.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9, 0x3F, 0x25)));
                item2.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);
                menu.addMenuItem(item2);
            }

            private void createMenu3(SwipeMenu menu) {
                SwipeMenuItem item1 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item1.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0x30, 0xB1, 0xF5)));
                item1.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_about);
                menu.addMenuItem(item1);
                SwipeMenuItem item2 = new SwipeMenuItem(getApplicationContext());
                item2.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9, 0xCE)));
                item2.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                item2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_share);
                menu.addMenuItem(item2);
            }
        };
        listView.setMenuCreator(creator);

        // 8. Set OnMenuItemClickListener
        listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuExpandableListView.OnMenuItemClickListenerForExpandable() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(int groupPostion, int childPostion, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(groupPostion);
                // childPostion == -1991 means it was the group's swipe menu was
                // clicked
                String s = "Group " + groupPostion;
                if (childPostion != SwipeMenuExpandableListAdapter.GROUP_INDEX) {
                    s += " , child " + childPostion;
                }
                s += " , menu index:" + index + " was clicked";
                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        // open
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // delete
                        // delete(item);
                        mAppList.remove(groupPostion);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void btnClick(View view) {

    }

    /**
     * Basically, it's the same as BaseExpandableListAdapter. But added controls
     * to every item's swipability
     *
     * @author yuchentang
     * @see android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter
     */
    class AppAdapter extends BaseSwipeMenuExpandableListAdapter {

        /**
         * Whether this group item swipable
         *
         * @param groupPosition
         * @return
         * @see com.allen.expandablelistview.BaseSwipeMenuExpandableListAdapter#isGroupSwipable(int)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isGroupSwipable(int groupPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Whether this child item swipable
         *
         * @param groupPosition
         * @param childPosition
         * @return
         * @see com.allen.expandablelistview.BaseSwipeMenuExpandableListAdapter#isChildSwipable(int,
         * int)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isChildSwipable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            if (childPosition == 0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition % 3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildTypeCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupType(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition % 3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupTypeCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView iv_icon;
            TextView tv_name;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                iv_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
                tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                view.setTag(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mAppList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return mAppList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return "The " + childPosition + "'th child in " + groupPosition + "'th group.";
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ContentViewWrapper getGroupViewAndReUsable(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                                                          ViewGroup parent) {
            boolean reUseable = true;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_list_app, null);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(convertView));
                reUseable = false;
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            ApplicationInfo item = (ApplicationInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
            holder.iv_icon.setImageDrawable(item.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
            holder.tv_name.setText(item.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
            return new ContentViewWrapper(convertView, reUseable);
        }

        @Override
        public ContentViewWrapper getChildViewAndReUsable(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                                                          ViewGroup parent) {
            boolean reUseable = true;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_list_app, null);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(convertView));
                reUseable = false;
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            if (null == holder) {
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            }

            ApplicationInfo item = (ApplicationInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.iv_icon.setImageDrawable(item.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
            holder.tv_name.setText("this is child");
            return new ContentViewWrapper(convertView, reUseable);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener l = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(true);
        }
    };

    private int dp2px(int dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Hereby, i am attaching screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I use smoothOpenMenu(position); with SwipeMenuExpandableListView?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Code,**

https://github.com/tycallen/SwipeMenu-Expandable-ListView.

Download and Import to Android studio.

Comment: i have tried this already but the expandable list which i am using doesn't have a parent node all are child nodes even the swipe in not working in it